# Ошибка jaK2filter module Joomla 3 Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

выводит ошибку Joomla jak2filter "Notice: Undefined offset: 31 in..... Notice: Undefined offset: 32 in...." и модуль не сохраняется. Не пойму в чем дело

```
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_extra_fields', 'e'));
        $query->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__k2_extra_fields_groups', 'g'). 'ON (' . $db->quoteName('e.group') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('g.id') . ')');
        $query->group('gid');
        $db->setQuery($query);

        $results = $db->loadObjectList();

        var_dump($results);
        foreach ($results AS $r) {
            $html[] = '<optgroup label="'.$r->gname.'">';
            $exid = explode('-jaex-', $r->eid);

            $exname = explode('-jaex-', $r->ename);
            //print_r($exid);
            foreach ($exid AS $k => $e) {
               echo $exname[$k]."<br>";
                $html[] = '<option '.(in_array('xf_'.$e, $this->value) ? ' selected="selected" ' : '').' value="xf_'.$e.'">'.$exname[$k].'</option>';
            }
            $html[] = '</optgroup>';

        }
```

var_dump($results) выдает

```
.....jaex-80-jaex-30-jaex-31-jaex-32-jaex-33-jaex-34-jaex-35-jaex-36-jaex-39".......
Несущая конструкция
Материал наружных стен
Высота потолков
Внутренняя от

Notice: Undefined offset: 31 in .../modules/mod_jak2filter/elements/requiredfield.php on line 60


Notice: Undefined offset: 31 in ......../modules/mod_jak2filter/elements/requiredfield.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined offset: 32 in ..../modules/mod_jak2filter/elements/requiredfield.php on line 60


Notice: Undefined offset: 32 in ..../modules/mod_jak2filter/elements/requiredfield.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined offset: 33 in ..../modules/mod_jak2filter/elements/requiredfield.php on line 60


Notice: Undefined offset: 33 in ...../modules/mod_jak2filter/elements/requiredfield.php on line 61
Район
Назначение
```

Типа эти поля под номером 30, 31, 32 существуют. Причем ошибки могут меняться например покажет что и еще 29 элемента нет.

Заметил, что строка при выводе запроса имеет максимальное значение 1024. То есть  ["ename"]=> string(1024) "Поиск места-jaex-

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в этом
Ограничение 1024.
У этой функции есть ограничение на объем выводимых данных. 
По умолчанию 1024 символа для каждого объединения - для каждой выводимой строки.
Если размер склееных данных больше, то он будет урезаться.
Чтобы расширить размер нужно выполнить команду SET group_concat_max_len =4096;